# C# Collection Filtering, where do I begin

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have a collection lets call it 'Users', aka a set of USER

A USER has a set of CONTACTs.

I simply want to get all CONTACTs for a given user in common with another user.

I'm learning about Lambda/Linq expressions but not sure if thats what I should be doing to solve this sort of collection filtering problem.

So really I'm just looking for a intersection of 2 sets.

Comment: You should learn LINQ. It utilizes lambda expressions but explicitly learning lambda won't help you in this case.

Comment: What's your input data? A collection of users + the name/id of two users?

Comment: Yep exactly that. 

I have started with something like this logic, but obviously it doesn't work:

this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get().Where(p => p.contacts == user.contacts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply do "==" on two collections. However, if the contacts have some kind of id and a user can't have the same contact twice, this is pretty easy to do:

```
User user = ...
var contactIds = user.Contacts.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray();
var usersWithMatchingContacts = this.unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get()
    // basically, we're checking that the number of matching contacts is the same as the
    // total number of contacts for the user, which means that the user has the same
    // set of contacts. If you just want to require some overlap, change 
    // the "== u.Contacts.Count" to "> 0"
    .Where(u => u.Contacts.Count(c => contactIds.Contains(c.Id)) == u.Contacts.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//input data
var firstId = 12;
var secondId = 23;

var firstUser = users.First(user => user.Id == firstId);
var secondUser = users.First(user => user.Id == secondId);

var commonContacts = firstUser.Contacts
                              .Where(contact =>
                                  secondUser.Contacts.Contains(contact))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQs Intersect method

```
var commonContacts = firstUser.Contacts.Intersect(secondUser.Contacts)
```

Comment: Also, I think it should be mentioned that the `Contact` class needs to have properly defined `Equals` and `HashCode` methods for this to work.